# ios - UITableView lags with multiple sections

Tags: ios, uitableview

Putting all my rows in one section performs great. Using the same number of rows in a large number of sections causes 2-6 seconds of lag, especially whenever the bottom of the UITableView displays.

Things I have tried:

- Changing `UITableViewStyleGrouped` to `UITableViewStylePlain`
- Setting `self.view.sectionHeaderHeight = 0.0`, or `0.01f` (based on suggestions I've seen). Same for `sectionFooterHeight`.
- Setting `self.view.tableHeaderView` and `self.view.tableFooterView` to empty views with height `0.0` or `0.01f`.
- Having `titleForHeaderInSection` delegate method return `nil`.
- Having `heightForHeaderInSection` return `0.0` or `0.01f`.
- Setting up `estimatedheightForRowAtIndexPath` to return the proper cell heights.

This is clearly a UITableView issue, because my cells layout just fine if they are all in the same section. Why is it so slow when there are multiple sections, or the footer area is laid out? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `UITableView` is fine dude, post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your UITableViewCells are not reuseable.

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell that how many sections do you have? Try to use estimatedSectionHeaderHeight and estimatedSectionFooterHeight.

Apple's api docs says: "Providing a nonnegative estimate of the height of section headers can improve the performance of loading the table view. If the table contains variable height section headers, it might be expensive to calculate all their heights when the table loads. Using estimation allows you to defer some of the cost of geometry calculation from load time to scrolling time."

This is about the estimatedSectionHeaderHeight, and this lazy-load mechanism works the same way for section footers.

Since you lag only when the section amount get large, I think this might help.